# Inconsistent behavior of the Blackberry Hardware Back button on Phonegap/JqueryMobile

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a multi page JqueryMobile(1.0) App and using Phonegap(1.3) to provide the WebView. I have been through stackoverflow and the web on code to handle the blackberry hardware back button.

I have set the mobile.pushStateEnabled=false before jquerymobile loads.
I have also set the config.xml file with the following feature

```
<feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
```

I have tried placing the following piece of code at various places. In the header/body/in all pages but I continue to get inconsistent behavior. Phonegap is getting initialized and I have even tried putting it in after phonegap intiialization but nothing seems to work. I have even tried by making it a single html file with all pages in one file(jquery mobile). The app either exits or in some cases does not respond at all and in rare cases behaves as expected.

```
<script>
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, 
function() { 
    history.back();
    return false;
}); 
</script>
```

I am using a Blackberry 9780 (OS ver 6..0) to deploy and have also tried it with the latest versions of jquery-mobile(1.01) and phonegap (1.4).
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}   

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener

document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}


function onBackKeyDown() {

history.back();
return false;
       }
</script>
```

and dont forget to add onLoad function in your onReady

Comment: Nope :(. Still inconsistent. I tried loading it from the pageinit as well. Also tried window.history.back() as well. Thanks for pointing this out. I am giving up on this for now. Has been quite frustrating dealing with Blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. Sometimes the app is just closed, sometimes it works, sometimes you have to press the back button several times.

Try one of this answers: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Back-button-in-BB-OS-5/m-p/1611047